# How to respond to company contact wishing to learn about my "current work?"

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, hiring

I was exploring a company whose work is exactly my area of training / current work.  I (believe?) I went through one of those options to say that "I am interested in what the company is doing and would like to hear more."  However, it was awhile back; perhaps the company just monitors users and decides to email them if they look at particular parts of the website (Google could certainly do this).

The body of the email I received is reproduce below, with keywords and names replaced.

> Hi Mr. X,
>
> Thank you for taking interest in and learning about [our company]. We
> hope our website was informative and you enjoyed reading our case
> studies.
>
> Please let me know if you have any questions. We'd be happy to have a
> call to learn about your work, to learn more about your interest in
> [our company], and to discover how we might have the opportunity to
> work together.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Mrs. Y
>
> Business Development

I am currently employed, but it is not a permanent full time job but as a research assistant in a university.  However, the research I am doing is in the same domain of the company's main research.  I certainly do not think I supplied any information that makes me sound like I am a consultant / full researcher looking to collaborate; instead I am interested in a position in the company.  My worry is that I do not want to accidentally misrepresent myself.  The lines about "learn about your work" and "discover how we might have the opportunity to work together" are what worry me.

The company offers a different email address and contact to correspond about a possible position.

My question is thus: should I

(1) respond to this email and set up a time to chat

(2) just go the hiring email route

(3) or do (1) and then (2) if (1) goes well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're over thinking this, looks like you filled in a form for more info, and you are getting a sales person contacting you with a standard email, which you can then respond to if you want to know more about their services.

I don't think they have monitored you and are contacting because they've worked out what you do (and want a job), it's just a standard sales pitch (so don't worry about the tinfoil hat just yet).

The job route is a different person and mail as it's a different part of the company that deals with it, if you want to apply go that route, arranging a call will just get a disgruntled sales person who thought they had a lead.